# Why does kotlin not compile when I have a return inside a lambda inside a loop

Tags: kotlin, lambda

So I have this very simple code:

```
val a:() -> String = a@ {
    while(true){
            return@a "hello"
    }
}
```

And intellij says:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: String
Found: Unit
```

Now, if I had the same thing, like, in a function

```
fun b():String {
    while(true){
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

It's totally fine.

I also can't use a `Callable`

```
val c : Callable<String> = Callable<String> {
    while(true){
        return@Callable "hello"
    }
}
```

Same error. I could convert it to an object decleration:

```
val d :Callable<String> = object :Callable<String>{
    override fun call(): String {
        while(true)
            return "hello"
    }
}
```

and that works. Why doesn't it work when using a lambda?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that by convention for lambda last statement is an implicit return, so your first block is treated as *something like this*:

```
function a(): String {
    return while (true) {
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

Which basically can be read as "return the result of while block" and it is considered as Unit.

You can use anonymous function instead to bypass this convention:

```
val a = fun(): String {
    while (true) {
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a lambda that has a non-`Unit` return type, the last statement must be an expression. `while` is not an expression, and thus Kotlin infers that the code block

```
while(true){
    return@Callable "hello"
}
```

is meant to return `Unit`. The compiler does not do deeper analysis to infer that it's an infinite loop with a non-local return statement.

As such, you must make sure that the last line of your lambda is an expression of type `String`.

I once built a helper function for scenarios where a certain *type* is expected, but not a value:

```
fun <T> declval(): T = throw IllegalStateException("Code should be unreachable")
```

It is modeled after [C++ std::declval()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval). So, your lambda could be:

```
val a:() -> String = a@ {
    while(true){
        return@a "hello"
    }

    declval<String>()
}
```

But it might be easier to understand if you just change the control flow of your infinite loop to result in one exit point (e.g. using `break`).

Comment: I ended up putting an `error(&quot;&quot;)` and the end of the block, and because error returns `Nothing` and `Nothing` is-a `String`, it compiles quite nicely.

It&#39;s probably better to use a combination of the two, something like `fun endOfLoop(): Nothing = error(&quot;Infinite loop exited without  returning&quot;)` 

I think the best option though is @ookami.kb&#39;s solution though, because it's less sketchy.